# Swapping Objects in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop, object, ownership

I am trying to swap two objects upon a button action, but I can't get it to work. It's swapping on first time, but next time when I click on the button, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here's the code

```
-(IBAction)swapLocation
{
    CCLocDTO *tempDto = searchDTO.toDTO;
    searchDTO.toDTO = searchDTO.fromDTO;
    searchDTO.fromDTO = tempDto;

    NSLog(@"From Location is %@",searchDTO.fromDTO.streetAddress); //it becomes empty on next button click
    NSLog(@"To Location is %@",searchDTO.toDTO.streetAddress);
    NSLog(@"From Special Location is %@",searchDTO.fromSpecialDTO.locationName);
    NSLog(@"To Special Location is %@",searchDTO.toSpecialDTO.locationName);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I am assigning fromDTO and toDTO in Search DTO(searchDTO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using ARC, you need to retain `tempDto` before you set `searchDTO.toDTO` to something else; otherwise the old value may be deallocated, and you will have a dangling reference in `tempDto`. It should look like this:

```
CCLocDTO *tempDto = [searchDTO.toDTO retain];
searchDTO.toDTO = searchDTO.fromDTO;
searchDTO.fromDTO = [tempDto autorelease];
```

or like this:

```
CCLocDTO *tempDto = [searchDTO.toDTO retain];
searchDTO.toDTO = searchDTO.fromDTO;
searchDTO.fromDTO = tempDto;
[tempDto release];
```

Comment: Isn't the default getter for retain properties implemented like `return [[bar retain] autorelease]`?

Comment: @JustSid nope, I'm pretty sure it just returns the ivar without touching the retain count.

Comment: @TomDalling You are right, sorry, that only happens for atomic properties! Sorry, I was at some other place with my head when I wrote that.

Comment: The behavior of synthesized getters is documented in [The Objective-C Programming Language > Declared Properties > Property Declaration Attributes > Atomicity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2).